# Изменение заголовка переходя по ссылке

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Здравствуйте, имеется страничка, которая содержит ссылки в главном меню, ниже этого меню расположен заголовок. Вопрос состоит в том: как изменить заголовок, перейдя по ссылке?

template.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
 xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />

<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css}" />

</head>
<body>
 <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a th:href="@{/http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->



 <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar navbar-default">
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <li th:each="page:${pages}"><a th:text="${page.title}" th:href="${page.url}">123</a></li>                
             </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
     <h1>Оглавление</h1>
 </div>


 <script th:src="@{/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js}"></script>
 <script th:src="@{/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Метод из контроллера

```
    @RequestMapping("/custom/{pageName}")
public String getCustomPage(@PathVariable String pageName, Model model) {
   GlPage p = pageService.findByUrl(pageName);

   if(!p.isPublished())
   {
       return "pagemanager";
   }
   else
   {
       ArrayList<GlPage> allPages = (ArrayList<GlPage>)pageService.getAllPages();
       model.addAttribute("pages", allPages);
       return "template";
   }
}
```

Comment: Не ясно чего вы хотите получить. Начиная с того, что считать заголовком -- тег `<title>`, тег `<h1>` или что-то еще? И как он должен меняться, что туда должно подставляться и по какому условию?

Comment: Тег <h1> является заголовком. Имеется класс GlPage, у которого есть атрибуты id, title, url, published. Вот этот кусок кода формирует меню с ссылками на все имеющиеся страницы. <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <li th:each="page:${pages}"><a th:text="${page.title}" th:href="${page.url}">123</a></li>                
             </ul>     Допустим я перехожу по первой ссылке, где url = star_wars, а title = Звездные войны. Так вот как мне подставить этот самый title в h1?

Answer (score 1):

> Допустим я перехожу по первой ссылке, где url = star_wars, а title = Звездные войны. Так вот как мне подставить этот самый title в h1?

В контроллере у вас есть эта самая страница, так? Пробросите ее во view и там выводите.

Пример:

```
GlPage p = pageService.findByUrl(pageName);
model.addAttribute("page", p);
```

и

```
<h1 th:text="${page.title}">Оглавление</h1>
```

Comment: У меня там массив всех страниц, который я передаю во view и есть ли возможность как-нибудь получить title текущей страницы, на которую я перешел?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Решил так: в контроллере создал переменную `GlPage currentPage =  pageService.findByUrl(url)`, а затем добавил ее в модель `model.addAttribute("currentPage", currentPage)` и вызвал ее в представлении `<h1 th:text="${currentPage.title}"></h1>`. Спасибо [@SlavaSemushin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/546101/6), подтолкнул на эту идею.

Comment: Для "спасибо" здесь есть особая кнопочка ;)